# PNG++ Read Pixel Color Values

Tags: c++, png, libpng

How do I read the pixel color values in a png with [png++](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/)? I dont see any way of reading values in the [documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.1/). I need to get all the values rgba seperately and append them to a char array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

can't add a comment, so here goes :)

Actually, you should want `image[Y][X]` since first `[]` gets you to `Y`-th row, and then to the `X`-th column in that row.

Btw, I'm the author of PNG++.  Feel free to ask more specific questions on the mailing list or at my private email, or here, if you like. :)

Comment: Thanks ;) Where should I look to change this to [X][Y]? Seems more logical to me. Also when will you be implementing this? quote from end_info.hpp ""// TODO: add methods to read/write text comments etc.""

Comment: @Neb: that's how `operator[]` works in C++: you may only pass one parameter to it.  In PNG++ image is thought of as vector of rows, so `image[N]` gets then Nth row.  If you want more intuitive way to access pixels, use `get/set_pixel(x,y)`.  It does have a penalty for checking the range of it's indexes.  About support for text comments: when I have enough free time and motivation or somebody sends in a really good patch. :)

Comment: @alex, could you shed some light on the internal memory layout of the pixels? For example, if the rows (scanlines?) are allocated together and packed, I could perhaps load a PNG as a texture into my OpenGL context using a pointer, rather than copying it out to memory pixel by pixel first. By the way, your library is neat and quite helpful. I bet I could probably answer this myself if I did some more digging, but I wanted to ask first. Thanks!

Comment: Well, with the default pixel buffer, the layout is not contiguous, but it should be easy to add such a buffer and specialize image class template to use that.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used png++, but from reading the [documentation on pixel](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.1/structpng_1_1basic__rgb__pixel.html) I think you can access a pixel (X,Y) of `png::image<T> image` with `image[Y][X]` and then access the red, green and blue values by accessing `image[Y][X].red`, etc.

Comment: I'll try it out. Im a beginner in c++ so I dont really understand much anyway :S